# Safari not animating gif in svg using greensock

Tags: svg, gsap

I have an svg which has an image with a mask , the image is an animated gif.
I'm then using TweenlineLite to move it across screen. This works fine in all browsers apart from safari. In safari it animated across screen but the animated gif doesn't work! However if i change the inital position of the svg to be on screen the gif animates.

Any ideas what this safari bug is? here is a codepen of the code [codepen](https://codepen.io/adamjw3/pen/dWOgdB)

```
var raven = document.getElementById("js-raven"),
width = $(window).width() + 200,

tl = new TimelineLite({
     delay: 2,
     onComplete: function() {
        this.restart();
    }
});
tl
.from(raven, 0, {x: -200})
.to(raven, 20, { x: width })
.to(raven, 0, { x: width, rotationY: 180, delay: 5 })
.to(raven, 40, { x: -width });
```

Comment: this is the bug tracker for webkit, you can search it and/or raise your bug there. https://bugs.webkit.org/query.cgi?format=specific&product=WebKit

Comment: thanks @RobertLongson, is this a bug or something i have done. i've noticed that if i also add the image as an img tag it animates fine, but it seems i have to have the graphic on screen

Comment: @RobertLongson Do you know a work around for this?

Comment: Sure, use Firefox instead!

Comment: @RobertLongson if only that was an option

Answer (score 0):

I discovered one way around this issue/bug.

Set a  tag with the same animated gif file and make the dimensions 1 x 1

e.g

```
<img src="resources/images/raven.gif" width="1" height="1">
```

This then enables you to animate off the screen and still have the gif playing